# Why are some long vowels transcribed with single, short IPA vowels?

Tags: phonology, phonetics

When transcribing English vowels phonetically, long vowel sounds are usually written with two IPA vowels when the vowel is at the end of word or syllable:

> *paper* /pei-/

But sometimes long vowels are written as a single, short IPA vowel instead; for example:

> *be* /bi/

Why is this?

Comment: You mean why /biˈfɔː/ and not /bɪˈfɔː/ or /biˈfɔː/? Because the people who decide how to write down phonetic transcriptions in dictionaries got carried away and are showing fine distinctions in pronunciation that lots of U.K. speakers don't even make.

Comment: @PeterShor I think OP is asking why some "long" vowels are represented with two glyphs and others with just one.

Comment: @StoneyB I don't think that's what the OP is asking about. There is a rule in British English that will not allow short vowels in stressable unchecked syllables. It sounds like the OP has understood only half of this rule ...

Comment: @araucaria Check OP's Title question... I think this is about the "long V"-"short V" distinction made by pedagogues teaching spelling, which OP is trying to relate to IPA and IPA-like representations. But I'm coming from US pedagogical practice, and if UK practice is different I may very well have misunderstood.

Comment: @StoneyB: Which title are you talking about? The title when you wrote that comment was written by Janus Bahs Jacquet, not the original poster. I rolled back that edit because, while it did make the question clearer, I'm not at all sure that it reflects the OP's original question.

Comment: @suməlic, Stoney, I'm not sure it's clear either way ... given the combination of the title plus the Q itself. However, I don't think we'll ever see this OP again to find out... I remember, not very pleasantly, my first attempts to interact with SE computer gumph. OP hasn't  been seen since they posted their Q ... Given that fact, it's probably best to reinstate the edit. Then SB's post will make sense and the Q will have some benefit for users. If OP comes back n responds to the comments we can adjust the Q accordingly - or get them to post a second Q. Otherwise it's just a car crash.

Comment: @suməlic or a srahcrac.

Comment: @suməlic By gum, you're right. Confirmation bias!

Comment: @Araucaria: I've decided not to touch this question any more, so I won't re-instate the edit myself, but I won't roll back again if someone else re-edits the question. I voted to close as "unclear", and I wish it had been closed before it was answered. But now that it's answered, I don't know what the best course of action would be.

Comment: @suməlic Well, maybe think about future readers, and let that be your guide.

Comment: @StoneyB I'm going to roll back the rollback, because I think that's what's best for future readers unless OP comes back and says he intended something different from what you and Janus interpreted as. See comments to and from Sumelic above.

Answer (score 6):

The traditional terms "long" and "short" for teaching English vowels were borrowed from Latin grammar back in the days when Latin was the only language for which formal grammatical discourse was available. These terms don't represent the linguistic facts of English. That is, some English vowels do have a longer duration than others, but the primary feature which distinguishes English vowels is not length, as it appears to have been in Latin, but "quality", the sound imposed by the variable shape of the oral cavity.

The representation of English vowels in IPA and similar systems of notation **does** represent the linguistic facts:

- "long a", "long i" and "long o" are ***diphthongs***—they consist of a glide from one sound to another—so they are represented with **two** glyphs each, /eɪ/, /aɪ/, /oʊ/ (or /əʊ/).
- "long e" and "long u", however, are ***monophthongs***—they consist of a single more or less homongeneous sound—so they are represented with **single** glyphs, /i/ and /u/.

Note that diphthongs are in fact, by default, longer than monophthongs, and that "long e" and "long u" are, in fact, usually pronounced with a longer duration (and consequently are often represented with a colon, or a glyph similar to a colon, to represent the increased length: /iː/, /uː/. That, no doubt, is why early English grammarians adopted the terms "long" and "short".

- "Short a, e, i, o, u" are also monophthongs, but they have different qualities than the long versions, and are represented with different glyphs: /æ/, /ɛ/ or /e/, /ɪ/, /ɒ/, /ʊ/ or /ʌ/ (depending on which sound your teacher names a "short u").
- There are also a whole bunch of vowels which don't have long/short distinctions, or even names, in traditional grammar, because they didn't occur in Latin (or at least weren't discussed by Latin grammarians). Some are diphthongs: "ow" /aʊ/, "oy" /ɔɪ/, and the vowels preceding /r/ in non-rhotic dialects like BrE, /eə/ as in "fair", /ʊə/ as in "cure", /ɪə/ as in "fear". Others are monophthongs: "aw" /ɔː/, "ah" /ɑː/, and the destressed central vowel /ə/.

Comment: I though "long" and "short" were terms carried over from Middle English and not Latin (although the "long" and "short" vowels in Middle English matched the ones from Latin pretty well.)

Comment: In British English the short and long vowels form two distinct classes with their own phonological properties. This is why TRAP is considered a short vowel in English even though it is almost as long as some of the long vowels. It phonologically belongs to the short vowel family. Often specific long and short vowels have a systematic relationship with each other. So, for example, we might see a long vowel when it appears in a short word and then its short relation when we add suffixes to that base. So the TRAP vowel and the FACE vowel, for example, have a special relationship in the system.

Comment: So, in other words, I don't think that OP is using the same type of description of long and short vowels that we use in school English lessons. However, until OP can give us the lowdown on what they are angling at I'll give you my +1. I do feel sorry for the OP. It's hard to describe this stuff especially if you need help with it because you don't understand it! :/ (Btw, when I said British English, I really meant SSBE, of course. Sorry)

Comment: @PeterShor I don't think we know of *any* discussion of English phonology, spelling or grammar before the 16th century, so if the terms derived from ME they were employed in the context of Latin grammar. But it's quite true that the Great Vowel Shift occurred during the LME-EModE centuries.

Comment: @StoneyB: The OED shows the terms were used in the context of Latin in the 15th century, and for English and French in the 16th century. So I would assume that the labels for English long vowels made more sense (and corresponded better with Latin) when they were first used, which was probably some time before the OED has citations for them.

Comment: @Araucaria Yah, that orthographic "systematic relationship" is a byproduct of the GVS, which operated mostly on the historically long vowels and left the short vowels mostly alone.

Comment: @PeterShor Indeed, though the GVS was well under way by the time the Tudors started activating for spelling reform.